# On the existence of a continuous section of $\zeta\in\mathbb{S}^1\mapsto(\zeta^m,\zeta^n)\in\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, circles, fundamental-groups

Let $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ and let define the following map:
$$f:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{S}^1&\rightarrow&\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1\\
\zeta&\mapsto&(\zeta^m,\zeta^n)
\end{array}\right..$$
I have to prove the following:

> **Proposition.** The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - There exists a continuous map $g:\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ such that $g\circ f=\textrm{id}_{\mathbb{S}^1}$.
> - $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

**Proof.**

- If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, using Bézout's there exists $(u,v)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $um+vn=1$ and the following map: 
  $$g:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
  \mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1&\rightarrow&\mathbb{S}^1\\
  (\zeta_1,\zeta_2)&\mapsto&{\zeta_1}^u{\zeta_2}^v
  \end{array}\right.$$
  is continuous and satisfies $g\circ f=\textrm{id}_{\mathbb{S}_1}$.
- If there exists $g:\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ such that $g\circ f=\textrm{id}_{\mathbb{S}^1}$, then $g_*\circ f_*=\textrm{id}_{\pi_1\left(\mathbb{S}^1,1\right)}$ and $f_*$ is injective. $\Box$
  I understand that one has:
  $$f_*:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
  \pi_1\left(\mathbb{S}^1,1\right)&\rightarrow&\pi_1\left(\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1,(1,1)\right)\\
  [\gamma]&\mapsto&[(\gamma^n,\gamma^m)].
  \end{array}\right.$$
  Despite I tried to use that $\left[e^{2i\pi\cdot}\right]$ is a generator of $\pi_1\left(\mathbb{S}^1,1\right)$, I am not able to determine further $f_*$. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it help to notice that if $d = \gcd(m, n)$, then $f$ is $d$-to-$1$? Particularly, you can factor $f$ through the standard $d$-fold covering $f:S^{1} \to S^{1}$ followed by $\zeta \mapsto (\zeta^{m/d}, \zeta^{n/d})$.

Comment: I understand that if $d$ is a common divisor of $m$ and $n$, then for every $\zeta\in\mathbb{S}^1$ and every $\xi\in\mu_d$, then $f(\zeta)=f(\xi\zeta)$. However, I don't know how to apply this result to get that $\textrm{gcm}(m,n)$ must be equal to $1$. Besides, can I determine explicitly $f_*$? Thanks for your input!

Comment: If you look at the level of mappings (rather than actions on fundamental groups), $f$ itself has to be injective if there exists a map $g:S^{1} \times S^{1} \to S^{1}$ such that $g \circ f$ is the identity. :)

Comment: You are indeed very right! I was too focus on the fundamental groups. Thank you again ! :)